# Why do I keep receiving the "failed to compile" error when using a react native template from online?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt9do.png)
I'm new to coding and I'm attempting to utilize a template offered from Instamobile. I keep receiving the same error message for multiple files with the template and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
Failed to compile
/Users/bdancy/trial-4/components/BackButton/BackButton.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../assets/icons/backArrow.png' in '/Users/bdancy/trial-4/components/BackButton'
```

Am I missing something on the install side or is there an issue with the code? Below is a snippet of the code from which this error arises.

```
import React from "react";
import { TouchableHighlight, Image, Text, View } from "react-native";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styles from "./styles";

export default class BackButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight
        onPress={this.props.onPress}
        style={styles.btnContainer}
      >
        <Image
          source={require("../../../assets/icons/backArrow.png")}
          style={styles.btnIcon}
        />
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}

BackButton.propTypes = {
  onPress: PropTypes.func,
  source: PropTypes.number,
  title: PropTypes.string,
};
```

Comment: Your error says that the image `backArrow.png` is not in the location you mentioned in require.

Comment: @Rohit The image is in the defined folder from what I can see. I'll try to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many `../`. Try

```
          source={require("../../assets/icons/backArrow.png")}
```